# p5 canvas cannot be sized by css

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, p5.js

I have a p5 canvas with an initial width and height of 200px (from the javascript). However, I have also set the width to 100% in javascript. Is there a way I can create a canvas in p5, and then set it's width and height properties using css?

css:

```
canvas {
  width: 100%;
}
```

javascript:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
}
function draw() {
  background(100);
}
```

See [my codepen](http://codepen.io/Awesomennjawarrior/pen/LWGdjR#code-area) that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is! The secret is that the width of the canvas from p5 is dynamically created, meaning that it gets applied at `element` level. There is no way of overriding that with specificity, so you need to raise a declaration as `!important`:

```
canvas {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Keep in mind that while you can easily specify a `width`, an element's `height` is relative to the **parent**. If you don't **have** a parent, it will default to 0px. In such a situation, it would try to adjust based purely on the height, making the canvas into a perfect square. You're able to set a percentage-based `width` with no parent because it assumes the width of the viewport if there is no parent of the target element.

In order to adjust the `height`, you would need to either use a pixel-based measurement, or make use of a **parent** that has a **fixed height**:

```
body {
  height: 100px;
}

canvas {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or:

```
canvas {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100px !important;
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](http://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/EWPEQP).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This works great, but it seems like if I define both the width and height, it still tries to keep the ratio of the original canvas. Is there a way to override that?

Comment: You can define whatever parameters you would like, so long as you use `!important`. You could also set the height: `canvas { width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; }` -- that way you will keep the aspect ratio. Keep in mind that a percentage-based height is relative to the parent, and **defaults** to 0px (so the P5 would override). I'll update my answer to mention this :)